# How to summarize rows on column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   Col2  Col3
0     5     8
1     1     0
2     3     5
3     4     1
4     0     7
```

How can I sum values and get rid of index. To make it looks like this?

```
   Col2  Col3
     13    21
```

**Sample code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() 
df["Col1"] = [0,2,4,6,2] 
df["Col2"] = [5,1,3,4,0]
df["Col3"] = [8,0,5,1,7]
df["Col4"] = [1,4,6,0,8]
df_new = df.iloc[:, 1:3]

print(df_new)
```

Comment: You can make the output look like whatever you want with the appropriate print statement. But to get the column sums you would just use `df_new.sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.sum()` to get the sums for each column. It produces a Series where each row contains the sum of a column. Transpose this to turn each row into a column, and then use `.to_string(index=False)` to print out the DataFrame without the index:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.sum()).T.to_string(index=False)
```

This outputs:

```py
 Col2  Col3
   13    21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df_new.sum(axis = 0)
df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```